# idiomatic clojure range/collision checking?

Tags: clojure, collision-detection

getting back into clojure, and i wrote this little thing to check if two boxes are colliding by checking if vertices of one are inside the other:

```
(defn around
  [val radius]
  (let [half (/ radius 2)
        low (- val half)
        high (+ val half)]
    [low high]))

(defn colliding?
  [this that]
  (let [[this-x1 this-x2] (around (:x this) (:w this))
        [this-y1 this-y2] (around (:y this) (:h this))
        [this-z1 this-z2] (around (:z this) (:l this))
        [that-x1 that-x2] (around (:x that) (:w that))
        [that-y1 that-y2] (around (:y that) (:h that))
        [that-z1 that-z2] (around (:z that) (:l that))]
    (or (and (or (<= that-x1 this-x1 that-x2)
                 (<= that-x1 this-x2 that-x2))
             (or (<= that-y1 this-y1 that-y2)
                 (<= that-y1 this-y2 that-y2))
             (or (<= that-z1 this-z1 that-z2)
                 (<= that-z1 this-z2 that-z2)))
        (and (or (<= this-x1 that-x1 this-x2)
                 (<= this-x1 that-x2 this-x2))
             (or (<= this-y1 that-y1 this-y2)
                 (<= this-y1 that-y2 this-y2))
             (or (<= this-z1 that-z1 this-z2)
                 (<= this-z1 that-z2 this-z2))))))
```

this smells pretty bad due to repetition but i'm not sure what the best approach is for cleaning this up. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code by using the fact that there is a collision in one direction *unless* the starting coordinate of one object is higher than the ending coordinate of the other.
I.e. a sufficient test is

```
(not (or (> this-x1 that-x2)
         (> that-x1 this-x2)))
```

which is equivalent to

```
(and (<= this-x1 that-x2)
     (<= that-x1 this-x2))
```

Using this, your `colliding?` may be simplified to

```
(defn colliding?
  [this that]
  (let [[this-x1 this-x2] (around (:x this) (:w this))
        [this-y1 this-y2] (around (:y this) (:h this))
        [this-z1 this-z2] (around (:z this) (:l this))
        [that-x1 that-x2] (around (:x that) (:w that))
        [that-y1 that-y2] (around (:y that) (:h that))
        [that-z1 that-z2] (around (:z that) (:l that))]
     (and (<= this-x1 that-x2)
          (<= that-x1 this-x2)
          (<= this-y1 that-y2)
          (<= that-y1 this-y2)
          (<= this-z1 that-z2)
          (<= that-z1 this-z2))))
```

If you then factor out a function `conflicting?` that checks for overlapping in one dimension,

```
(defn conflicting?
  [this that coordinate size]
  (let [[this-c1 this-c2] (around (coordinate this) (size this))
        [that-c1 that-c2] (around (coordinate that) (size that))]
    (and (<= this-c1 that-c2)
         (<= that-c1 this-c2)))
```

`colliding?` can be further simplified by utilizing mapping over dimensions and sizes:

```
(defn colliding?
  [this that]
  (every? true? (map #(conflicting? this that %1 %2)
                     [:x :y :z]
                     [:w :h :l])))
```

**Edit:**

Furthermore, `conflicting?` may be simplified to

```
(defn conflicting?
  [this that coordinate size]
  (<= (math/abs (- (coordinate this) (coordinate that)))
      (/ (+ (size this) (size that)) 2)))
```

making the function `around` obsolete for the purpose of detecting collisions.

Comment: this is definitely the kind of thing i thought was possible, thanks! it feels a lot better to process the xyz/whl parameters in a map. simplifying the math also helps.